# CASE expression evaluation issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count, group-by, case

I have a SQL query which computes CourseType based on Description as below.

```
   SELECT    sc.EXSJ_Description,
   sn.STEN_Student_ID , s.STUD_Forename_1, s.STUD_Surname, 
    CASE 
    WHEN sc.EXSJ_Description IN ('FUNCTIONAL SKILLS - ENGLISH (LEVEL 1 & LEVEL  2)',
    'ENGLISH (ENTRY LEVEL)', 'FUNCTIONAL SKILLS ENGLISH') THEN 'Overall'
    WHEN sc.EXSJ_Description IN ('READING -ENGLISH LEVEL 2', 'READING- ENGLISH (LEVEL 1 )', 
    'E2  ENGLISH FUNTIONAL SKILLS READING', 'E2 FUNCTIONAL SKILLS READING', 
    'E3 ENGLISH FUNTIONAL SKILLS READING')THEN 'Reading' 
    WHEN sc.EXSJ_Description IN  ('WRITING- ENGLISH (LEVEL 1 )', 'WRITING- ENGLISH LEVEL  2', 
    'E2 ENGLISH FUNCTIONAL SKILLS WRITING', 'E3 ENGLISH FUNCTIONAL SKILLS WRITING') 
    THEN 'Writing' 
    WHEN sc.EXSJ_Description IN ('SPEAKING & LISTENING- 
ENGLISH LEVEL 2', 'SPEAKING & LISTENING- ENGLISH (LEVEL 1)',
    'E3 ENGLISH FUNCTIONAL SKILLS SPEAKING AND LISTENING', 
'E2 ENGLISH FUNCTIONAL SKILLS SPEAKING AND LISTENING') 
    THEN 'Speaking & Listening' 
    END AS CourseType,
    CASE WHEN e.EXSS_Act_Grade = 'PA' THEN 'Pass' 
    WHEN e.EXSS_Act_Grade = 'FL' THEN 'Fail' 
    WHEN e.EXSS_Act_Grade = 'X' THEN 'Not Attended' END AS Grade
    FROM         
    sql10.NG.dbo.STEN AS sn
LEFT OUTER JOIN sql10.NG.dbo.EXSSexmstsbj AS e 
    ON e.EXSS_Student_ID = sn.STEN_Student_ID 
    AND sn.STEN_Provision_Code = e.EXSS_Provision_Code 
    AND sn.STEN_Provision_Instance = e.EXSS_Provision_Instance
INNER JOIN sql10.NG.dbo.STUDstudent AS s 
    ON s.STUD_Student_ID = sn.STEN_Student_ID
    INNER JOIN sql10.NG.dbo.EXSJexsubject AS sc 
    ON sc.EXSJ_Subject_Code = e.EXSS_Subject_Code
WHERE (e.EXSS_Year = '2015') 
    AND (sn.STEN_Year = '2015') 
    AND (e.EXSS_Awarding_Body IN ('13', '73')) 
    AND (e.EXSS_Provision_Code LIKE 'MA27%') 
    AND (sn.STEN_Provision_Code LIKE '27%') OR
    (sn.STEN_Provision_Code LIKE 'MA27%') 
    AND (sc.EXSJ_Description LIKE '%englis%')
    GO
```

So there should be 3 Course Types - Overall, Reading or Writing but when I execute the query I see some NULL values which is not expected.

[image: SQL Query Results NULL CourseType]

Sample data:

```html
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[STEN](
 [STEN_ISN] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [STEN_Student_ID] [char](12) NOT NULL,
 [STEN_Year] [smallint] NOT NULL,
 [STEN_Provision_Code] [char](20) NOT NULL,
 [STEN_Provision_Instance] [char](6) NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[STEN](
VALUES 
 (‘13068629’, ‘2015’, ‘27107’, ‘151601’),
(‘14072552   ’, ‘2015’, ‘27107’, ‘151601’),
(‘14073353’, ‘2015’, ‘27107’, ‘151601’),
(‘14073645’, ‘2015’, ‘27107/DR01’, ‘151601’),
(‘15075375’, ‘2015’, ‘27107/DR01’, ‘151601’))
```

```html
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EXSSexmstsbj](
     [EXSS_Year] [smallint] NOT NULL,
     [EXSS_Student_ID] [char](12) NOT NULL,
     [EXSS_Act_Grade] [char](6) NOT NULL,
     [EXSS_Awarding_Body] [char](16) NOT NULL,
     [EXSS_Provision_Code] [char] (20) NULL,
     [EXSS_Provision_Intance] [char] (6) NULL))
    INSERT INTO  dbo.EXSSexmstsbj
    VALUES  ( 2015, ‘09054118’,’PA, ‘13’, ‘MA27031/A01’, ‘151601’),
    ( 2015, ‘1261589’,’PA, ‘13’, ‘MA27031/A01’, ‘151601’),
    ( 2015, ‘1364766’,’FL, ‘13’, ‘MA27031/A01’, ‘151601’),
    ( 2015, ‘1365244’,’FL, ‘13’, ‘MA27031/A01’, ‘151601’),
    ( 2015, ‘1260791’,’X, ‘13’, ‘MA27031/A01’, ‘151601’),
```

```html
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PRPIProvisionInstance](
 [PRPI_ISN] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [PRPI_Code] [char](20) NOT NULL,
 [PRPI_Instance] [char](6) NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[PRPIProvisionInstance]
VALUES (‘19235’,’27107’,’151601’),
(‘19236’,’27107/DR01’,’151601’),
(‘19285’,‘27113’, ‘151601’),
(‘19286’,’27113/DR01’,’151601’),
(‘19237’,’27120’,’151601’)
```

```html
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PRPHProvisionHeader](
 [PRPH_Code] [char](20) NOT NULL,
 [PRPH_Title] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
 [PRPH_ML2] [char](6) NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[PRPHProvisionHeader]VALUES(‘27000’,  ‘FS workshop for Art’, ‘A+D ‘),
(27000/A01’,’FS workshop for Art’,’A+D  ‘),
(‘27031/A01’,’FS English L2 (MA) (Pearson)’,’ WFD ‘),
(‘27032/A01’,’FS Maths L2 (MA) (Pearson)’,’ WFD ‘) ,
(‘27100/E91’,’EDEX English E1 FS Sept Start (13195) Tue 6.00-9.00’,’ PLW  ‘)
```

```html
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[STUDstudent](
 [STUD_Student_ID] [char](12) NOT NULL,
 [STUD_Surname] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
 [STUD_Forename_1] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
 ) 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[STUDstudent]
(‘703666V’, ‘Aakel’,’Gail’),
(‘472833M’,’Abbott’,’Emma’),
(‘481691M’,’Abbasi’,’Anisa’),
‘13072746’,’Ababio’,’Anita’),
‘13070877’,’Aaronson’, ‘Fay’)
```

```html
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EXSJexsubject](
 [EXSJ_Description] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
 [EXSJ_Awarding_Body] [char](16) NOT NULL,
 )
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EXSJexsubject]
VALUES (‘E1  ENGLISH FUNCTIONAL SKILLS SPEAKING AND LISTENING’, ‘13‘),
(‘E1 ENGLISH FUNTIONAL SKILLS READING’,’ 13 ‘),
(‘E1 ENGLISH FUNCTIONAL SKILLS WRITING’,’ 13 ‘),        
(‘E2 ENGLISH FUNCTIONAL SKILLS SPEAKING AND LISTENING’,’13’),              
(‘E2  ENGLISH FUNTIONAL SKILLS READING’,’ 13 ‘)
```

```html
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GNUCustom](
 [GNUC_Type] [char](4) NOT NULL,
 [GNUC_Entity_ISN] [int] NOT NULL,
GNUC_Text_1 [VARCHAR] (100) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO VALUES
(PRPI 571 
PRPI 7761 
PRPI 8292 
PRPI 8346 
PRPI 8374 
)
```

Kindly suggest where am I going wrong.

Thanks,
Ar

Comment: all your conditions are failing and there is no `else` condition, so the rows not satisfying any of the conditions would get `null`s

Comment: Just look into your SQL: It's a typo ... `E2  ENGLISH FUNTIONAL SKILLS READING` misses a `C`, same with `E3...` :-)

Comment: Shnugo - It appears like that in student database as well probably it was typo while entering the data

Comment: Case expressions, not case statements...

Comment: We have neither your tables nor your data, you expect us to diagnose why the query doesn't work as you expect? Please try to *trim* your query down to just the vital parts of the question, similarly give us the minimal table structures that the trimmed query will use (ideally as `CREATE` statements) and some sample data (ideally as `INSERT` statements) and what your *expected* output is.

Comment: `sc.EXSJ_Description` & `e.EXSS_Act_Grade` wheather both contains data in upper case or lower case??

Comment: Thanks for adding the sample data but perhaps you missed the bit about trimming your query down? Do we really need 7 tables to reproduce the actual *issue*? Can you not reproduce it with a simpler query and perhaps just one or two tables?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Please see updated query above...hope it looks better now...

Comment: Did you find any of the problems yet?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that there are some other values within EXSJ_Description column that are not being picked up in your `CASE WHEN` statements.

Try this command see if it returns any non-null values:

```
SELECT  
     EXSJ_Description
FROM 
     sql10.NG.dbo.EXSJexsubject
WHERE 
     EXSJ_Description
     NOT IN 
         ('FUNCTIONAL SKILLS - ENGLISH (LEVEL 1 & LEVEL  2)',
         'ENGLISH (ENTRY LEVEL)',
         'FUNCTIONAL SKILLS ENGLISH',
         'WRITING- ENGLISH (LEVEL 1 )',
         'WRITING- ENGLISH LEVEL  2',
         'E2 ENGLISH FUNCTIONAL SKILLS WRITING',
         'E3 ENGLISH FUNCTIONAL SKILLS WRITING',
         'SPEAKING & LISTENING- ENGLISH LEVEL 2',
         'SPEAKING & LISTENING- ENGLISH (LEVEL 1)',
         'E3 ENGLISH FUNCTIONAL SKILLS SPEAKING AND LISTENING',
         'E2 ENGLISH FUNCTIONAL SKILLS SPEAKING AND LISTENING')
```

If there are, add them to your conditions. In the future, best practice dictates always using an `ELSE` to catch any unmatched values.

If they are all null, your joins are probably causing a duplication of data that's creating extra null values. Without your data set it's hard to tell for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Although using exact matches may be desirable in some cases, having lists of exact matches offers the opportunity for typos and may cause maintenance problems in the future.

You might consider using pattern matching here to make the code easier to follow:

```
(CASE WHEN sc.EXSJ_Description LIKE 'FUNCTIONAL%' OR 
           sc.EXSJ_Description LIKE '%ENTRY%'
     THEN 'Overall'
     WHEN sc.EXSJ_Description LIKE '%READING%'
     THEN 'Reading' 
     WHEN sc.EXSJ_Description LIKE '%WRITING%'
     THEN 'Writing' 
     WHEN sc.EXSJ_Description LIKE '%SPEAKING%LISTENING%'
     THEN 'Speaking & Listening' 
     ELSE 'Unknown'
END) AS CourseType,
```

Admittedly, this will not work for all naming conventions (if a description has both `READING` and `WRITING`, then what?).  But it does work for your particular set of names and it reduces the opportunities for a typo, which caused your original problem.

Comment: While this may fix the problem, it has potential to cause coding errors. From these values alone we see that they have overlapping keywords, so `LIKE` conditions that are too broad could cause values to be placed in categories in which they don't belong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, but not good from performance perspective

```
CASE
    WHEN REPLACE(sc.EXSJ_Description,' ','') IN (
                        REPLACE('FUNCTIONAL SKILLS - ENGLISH (LEVEL 1 & LEVEL  2)',' ',''),
                        REPLACE('ENGLISH (ENTRY LEVEL)',' ',''),
                        REPLACE('FUNCTIONAL SKILLS ENGLISH',' ','')
                    ) THEN 'Overall'
    WHEN REPLACE(sc.EXSJ_Description,' ','') IN (
                       REPLACE('READING -ENGLISH LEVEL 2',' ',''),
                       REPLACE('READING- ENGLISH (LEVEL 1 )',' ',''), 
                       REPLACE('E2  ENGLISH FUNTIONAL SKILLS READING',' ',''),        
                       REPLACE('E2 FUNCTIONAL SKILLS READING',' ','') 
                       REPLACE('E3 ENGLISH FUNTIONAL SKILLS READING',' ','')
                   )THEN 'Reading' 
    WHEN REPLACE(sc.EXSJ_Description,' ','') IN  (
                       REPLACE('WRITING- ENGLISH (LEVEL 1 )',' ',''),
                       REPLACE('WRITING- ENGLISH LEVEL  2',' ',''), 
                       REPLACE('E2 ENGLISH FUNCTIONAL SKILLS WRITING',' ',''), 
                       REPLACE('E3 ENGLISH FUNCTIONAL SKILLS WRITING',' ','')
                   )THEN 'Writing' 
    ...
    ...
```